# In a Control extension, Override or addHandler?

Tags: c#, wpf

I created an Extension for the DataGrid. I would like to know what is the better way to do thing in event.

Is it better to add an Handler like this :

```
class MyDataGrid : DataGrid {
    public MyDataGrid() {
        this.PreviewKeyDown+= MyDataGrid_PreviewKeyDown;
    }

    protected void MyDataGrid_PreviewKeyDown(/* args */) {/* do stuff */}
}
```

or with override like this:

```
class MyDataGrid : DataGrid {
    public MyDataGrid() { }
    protected override void OnPreviewKeyDown(/* args */) {/* do stuff */}
}
```

And if I let `base.OnPreviewKeyDown(e);` in the override, does it do the same as the eventHandler?

Comment: Yes both are equivalent if you call base method from overridden method.

Comment: The second snippet is better.  It forces you to think about a detail you haven't thought about yet.  Do you call base.OnPreviewKeyDown() before your "do stuff"?  Or after?  Or not at all?  Good odds that you don't know right now because you haven't thought about it yet.  It matters.  The problem with the event is that you can't fix it if it turns out that it *did* matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It probably does not matter either way.  That said, you should override the method -- its whole purpose is to handle the event from within the control.  If you add an event handler, then you are needlessly adding another method to the event's invocation list (ie, slight performance hit).

If you want to be strict/fanatical about performance, then you could also make your "MyDataGrid" class "sealed".

```
sealed class MyDataGrid : DataGrid { ... }
```

That allows compiler/runtime to determine that it doesn't need to check for any overrides of the virtual method "OnPreviewKeyDown" above your "MyDataGrid" class.